# Export everything but a few items in Typescript

Tags: typescript, export

I'd like to export everything from a module except for a few functions that I'd like to override.  Something like this:

```
import * as Base from "base-module";
const extendMeOld = Base.extendMe;
delete Base.extendMe;

export * from Base;

export function extendMe() {
  extendMeOld();
  someOtherCode();
}
```

How can this be achieved with Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly, but this works:

```
import { extendMe as extendMeOld } from "base-module";

export function extendMe() {
  extendMeOld();
  someOtherCode();
}

// @ts-ignore
export * from Base;
```

I guess whatever is exported first takes precedence.  I was surprised and expected it to be the opposite (export overwrite), but perhaps module resolution is a runtime thing?

Anyways, one overloads the other and `tsc` will get mad about it, but you can just make it ignore the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep it tree shakable id suggest the following

```
export { doNotExtendMe, meNeigher } from "base-module";
import { extendMe as extendMeOld } from "base-module";

export function extendMe() {
  extendMeOld();
  someOtherCode();
}
```

Comment: I can't list exports individually.  There's too many, and they may change.